# I want to move the image left and right only

Tags: ios, swift, touchesbegan

I want to move this boat image with touches. It needs to move only left and right but not up and down. The problem is with this basic code setup, The image is moving all around.

I have the following code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var boat:UIImageView!
var stone:UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

func start() {

boat = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "boat"))
boat.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 90)
boat.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - boat.frame.size.height - 10
boat.center.x = self.view.bounds.midX

self.view.addSubview(boat)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    start()
    movingStone()
    intersectsAt()



}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch : UITouch = touches.first as UITouch!

    location = touch.location(in: self.view)
    boat.center = location


}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch : UITouch = touches.first as UITouch!
       location = touch.location(in: self.view)

    boat.center = location
}

func movingStone() {


    stone = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "stones.png"))
    stone.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
    var stone2 = 10 + arc4random() % 20

    stone.bounds = CGRect(x:10, y:10, width:40.0, height:40.0)
    stone.contentMode = .center;
    stone.layer.position = CGPoint(x: Int(stone2), y: 10)
    stone.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 3.142)


    self.view.insertSubview(stone, aboveSubview: myView)



    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.stone.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height + self.stone.frame.height + 10
    }) { (success:Bool) -> Void in

        self.stone.removeFromSuperview()
        self.movingStone()

    }



}
func intersectsAt() {


  if(boat.layer.presentation()?.frame.intersects
((stone.layer.presentation()?.frame)!))! {
            boat.image = UIImage(named: "wreckboat.png")

        }

    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update only the x coordinate of the image not the y coordinate.

Try this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch : UITouch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let loc_tmp = touch.location(in: self.view)

    // only use the x coordinate of the touch location
    location = CGPoint(x: loc_tmp.x, y: boat.center.y)
    boat.center = location


}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch : UITouch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let loc_tmp = touch.location(in: self.view)

    // only use the x coordinate of the touch location
    location = CGPoint(x: loc_tmp.x, y: boat.center.y)
    boat.center = location
}
```

Comment: Hey this works, how to set bounds as the image is going out of scope

and when I intersect boat and image it throws an error Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0

Comment: can you show what you mean? I did not understand it correctly

Comment: I have updated the code. I want to intersect boat and stone using touch if it interests the image of the boat is changed

Comment: I am changing the boat image from normal to wreckboat and I think I am calling it too early i guess, based on touch and intersection I want to change the image!

Comment: It looks like you are trying to program a game without SpriteKit. Thats not a good approach. If you want to make fancy stuff with colliding object, use Spritekit framework. You could do this also this way but, this will be very hard and confusing. Use spritekit framework instead. There you have many given logic for collisions of objects and stuff like that. So you dont need to program it yourself.

Comment: I used UILongGestureRecognizer and implemented the collision, but when Using the touches it not colliding and  I want to building from scartch.

both the objects are not interescting but it passes through touches began is used.

Comment: Any idea will be helpful collision is detected when UILongPressGestureRecognizer is used but not when touches began

Comment: I fixed it! 


       func intersectsAt(tap2 : Timer) {
        
        
        var f1 : CGRect!
        var f2 : CGRect!
        
        f1 = boat.layer.presentation()?.frame
        f2 = stone.layer.presentation()?.frame
        if(f1.intersects(f2)) {
            stopGame()
            
        }
        
    }

Comment: I still think that you should learn how to do this kind of stuff with spritekit framework instead of doing it on your own.

Comment: Yes, now I did this from scratch and from now onwards I will use SpriteKit. Thank you for the accurate answer touchesBegan and location.

Comment: The boat is moving to the extreme left and right of the screen. How to limit the range?

Comment: you can check the x coordinate for a specific range and if its not in that range dont set the center point of the boat

Comment: are you saying something like this ? location = CGPoint(x: loc_tmp.x, y: boat.center.y)
        if loc_tmp.x < CGFloat(rightS) && loc_tmp.x > CGFloat(leftS) {
        
        boat.center = location
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142176/discussion-between-prasanna-vigneshwar-and-kingalione).